# Is there any way to retrieve password from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am managing SQL server database along with Firebase. I have created user's account in Firebase from back-end by below method and stores other properties
in Firebase by providing User UID as unique key.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password).then(function (user) {

        firebase.database().ref("Users/" + user.uid + "/").set({
            favouriteId: FavouriteId,
            hotelId: HotelRef,
            isActive: IsActive,
            isLoggedIn: IsLoggedIn,
            name: Name,
            vendorId: VendorId
        }) });
```

User can use above credentials to login into mobile app.To change password of user I am using reset password by email from Firebase. Here Password is changing from mobile side and I am unable to update that password in SQL server.I want to update new password in SQL server database.

I have searched for above but I didn't find any solution or other way to get password from Firebase.

Currently I am calling API from mobile side to update password in SQL server.
Is there any way to retrieve updated password from Firebase database?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you storing the password (never a good idea to store plain text password) when Firebase Auth already does this for you securely using best practices including salting and hashing the password. If you plan to use Firebase Auth, you may as well let them manage password authentication for you. If you need to migrate to another auth system at some point in time, Firebase Auth provides multiple tools to get the hashed passwords via [CLI SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) and [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).